# How to search all WikiNews articles under specific category?

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

I'm trying to use WikiMedia API (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to search all articles under specific categories (https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Category:News_articles_by_section). For instance, find the text of all news articles under `Politics and Conflicts` (https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Category:Politics_and_conflicts).

So far, I've tried the Search API function (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search). However, it doesn't seem to accept `Deepcategory` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CategoryMember` API (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers).

For instance, to list 500 recent news articles in `Politics and Conflicts` sorted by `timestamp` use the following request:

```
https://en.wikinews.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Politics_and_conflicts&cmprop=ids|title|timestamp&cmsort=timestamp&cmdir=desc&cmlimit=500
```

Comment: You can also search for the list of categories in a specific language version using this 'https://tr.wikinews.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allcategories&acprop=size&acprefix=Politika'